# Why is a TFS secret not a SecureString?

Tags: powershell, security, tfs

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=tfs-2018&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#secret-variables) you have to pass a secret in TFS 2018 to powershell like this:

```
Param(
   [string]$sauceArgument,
   [string]$secretSauceArgument
)
Write-Host No problem reading $env:SAUCE or $sauceArgument
Write-Host But I cannot read $env:SECRET_SAUCE
Write-Host But I can read $secretSauceArgument "(but the log is redacted so I do not
           spoil the secret)"
```

Passing it as string does not allow using the secret in credentials. I am only able to use it when I convert it via ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText, which is supposed to be bad practise according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $secretSauceArgument -AsPlainText -Force
```

If I change the input type from [String] to [SecureString], I get this conversion error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'secretSauceArgument'. Cannot convert the "***" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

Does it really have to be converted at all? Does this mean using Secrets is bad practise?

Update to clarify my question: I am able to pass secrets into powershell. I am not able to use secrets as credentials (only via ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force which is bad practise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret variables in Azure DevOps pipeline are encrypted at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key. Secrets are available on the agent for tasks and scripts to use.

You used variable prefix `secret` that are reserved by the system, so you couldn't read it. Try to modify the variable name not use variable prefixes that are reserved by the system.

Check [Variable characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-characters):

> User-defined variables can consist of letters, numbers, `.`, and `_`
> characters. Don't use variable prefixes that are reserved by the
> system. These are: `endpoint`, `input`, `secret`, and `securefile`.
> Any variable that begins with one of these strings (regardless of
> capitalization) will not be available to your tasks and scripts.

---

Update:

Now I understand your issue better. From my test, even you defined the `$password = '123'` in your script, you still need `-AsPlainText -Force`. All variables defined in a script are treated as strings, there is no `SecureString` in pipeline.  You may try creating a secure string from an encrypted string in a file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--create-a-secure-string-from-an-encrypted-string-in-a-file.

Comment: If I change the name to mySauce, I get the same error: Cannot process argument 
transformation on parameter 'mySauce'. Cannot convert the "***" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

Comment: I used the names of the documentation example, so that is wrong according to the site you linked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=tfs-2018&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-variables-in-scripts

Comment: In your original post, you mentioned documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=tfs-2018&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#secret-variables, so I assumed you have set secrets in the web interface of the pipeline.

Comment: If you set a variable from a script, you could use prefix `secret`. A script in your pipeline can define a variable so that it can be consumed by one of the subsequent steps in the pipeline. All variables set by this method are treated as strings.

Comment: Not sure if we talking about the same issue: I am able to pass secrets from web interface and from script to other tasks. Works fine. I am not able to use secrets as SecureString in powershell. I thought a secret is supposed to be used for credentials and should therefore be a SecureString or safely be converted to SecureString. (I can only convert with the AsPlainText which is bad practise)...

Comment: All variables defined in a script are treated as strings. Could you elaborate "Passing it as string does not allow using the secret in credentials."? Could you provide a sample?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229146/discussion-between-tomwaitforitmy-and-cece-dong-msft).

Answer (score 0):

My personal takeaway is: TFS secrets are not optimal for credentials in powershell - which is a surprise, because I would expect secrets main purpose to be used for credentials.

The answer by Cece Dong - MSFT using a file instead is a solid alternative.

Comment: I know that. Thank you.